# DSX local - Models not working

Tags: dsx-local

I have installed a DSX 3 node cluster on RHEL 7.4, all notebooks and r-studio code work fine. However, model creation gives this error:

Load Data
Error: The provided kernel id was not found. Verify the input spark service credentials

All kubernetes pods seem to be up and running. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the Sept release, suggest stop kernels and restart. There was a limit of of 10 kernels in that release. You will see the active green button across notebooks/models with option to stop.